# Javascript ESC/POS Printing: How to set align left and right at the same line?

Tags: javascript, printing, pos

I need to set left align and right align at the same line.

Something like this:

```
Apple                   $1.0
Banana                  $1.0
```

What `POS` command should I use?

I need this code to work on different printers.

Comment: Did you actually mean Point of Sale or does POS mean something else for you?

Comment: Yes, `POS` printers have common commands to manipulate the text. I need to know the command to align left and right at the text at the same line.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code is `ESC a n` where `n` is 0, 1, or 2, corresponding to left, center, and right. However this is a line control command which means it controls the whole line and you can't have two different alignments for the same line. However, POS printers typically use fixed width characters so it should be possible to manually align the characters by inserting the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the max character for the line? I tried to deal with any kind of printers. Each printer has different max character in each line.

Comment: Depending on the language of the application and the model of the printer, it may be possible to guess by obtaining the number of dots in the [paper width](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=234#gs_lparen_ce_fn06). However, it is almost impossible with existing JavaScript libraries such as web browsers and node.js. It is realistic to prepare multiple print digit information as configuration information on the application side so that it can be selected and changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
string apple = "apple";
string price = "$1.0";

apple = apple.PadRight(48 - price.length) + price;
```

Comment: JavaScript has no `PadRight` method. Where is the magic number 48 coming from?

Comment: Yes you right about the PadRight method, but it is not complicated to create such a method.

Comment: For the '48' I remember that in the past when I checked the number of letters that fit on an 80mm roll page (in terminal printer), it was 48 letters... Of course, if you change the size of the text, then this number will change.